# How exclude module from projetc build in sbt from command line?

Tags: scala, sbt

`build.sbt` is like that:

```
lazy val root = project
  .in(file("."))
  .aggregate(
    `project1`,
    `project2`,
    `project3`
  )
```

I run `clean test`

The question is how to run `clean test` and skip build for `project3` without source modification?

Comment: In shell (interactive) mode, this would happen automatically I believe.

Comment: Otherwise you can explicitly choose to run a command for a single project but I don't think you can exclude one.

Comment: When you say "without code modification" do you mean that there has been no change in `project3` or that you want to skip the build without changing the build definition? If it's the former, `clean` causes all the information about the previous build to be discarded, so a full compilation is required for you to run `test`. Why do you need to run `clean`?

Answer (score 0):

By default, sbt uses incremental compilation, so `project3` won't be compiled unless the files changes.

By running `clean` before `test`, all the incremental compile status is removed, causing a recompilation. That's the point of clean. If that's not the behavior you want, remove `clean`

Comment: I think `clean` breaks this.

Comment: Ah yes, that's true. The point of `clean` is to erase incremental compile status and recompile. Don't invoke it if that's not what you want